# Rackspace Cloud Sites: Compute Cycles exploding. Very expensive

Tags: web-server, cloud, rackspace, cloud-hosting

Since last week my compute cycles (CC) went through the roof (Rackspace Cloud Sites). Normally I stay under the 10,000 cycles per month . Now this month I already have more than 75,000 compute cycles. I don't have more visitors and I did not change anything in the code. I looked in the raw log files, that didn't help either...

This explosion of CC already costs me more than 750 USD right now. And still counting.

Anyone know what to do? I have contacted Rackspace last week. But still no solution/answer.... Looks like Rackspace is liking the money!

Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not ask for it to be capped? seems like it's a license for them to print money if you can't. What tools do they provide for you?

Comment: +1 Feels like they should provide you with a detailed enough analysis of why the charge dramatically spiked, if it's as you say and nothing else changed. Also, posing the view of a paranoid, perhaps someone's compromised your site and is using it for other purposes, perhaps not showing up in the logs you can get to. If the code hasn't changed, wipe and reload the latest code-base from before the problem and see if it helps...

Comment: Good point OD :)

Comment: Don't just wipe and reload...reload from known-good base and install something that monitors file changes, like tripwire or other utility, and log to another machine activity such as logins. Otherwise whatever was compromised may simply be compromised again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cap the CC per site. Thats what we do with our Rackspace Cloud Sites.

Also do you have any cron jobs running which could cause an issue? ie backup etc?

Comment: Well from the raw logs it seems that another server (unknown domain/IP) is requesting 2 files every second or so from our Cloud Site. That's why the explosion of Compute Cycles. But every request is counted for the compute cycles. Anyone knows how to prevent this? Because this way it's very easy for others to increase my costs...

Comment: I would move the files to CloudSites and make the folder private so that only you can access it